# Difficulties changing between viewControllers in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 3 different viewControllers. first one is the main page where you will see many thumbnail of images. Second controller will only open when an image is clicked. Last ViewController is the login which opens when the user is not logged in but trying to view the second controller or clicked login from the main controller. In the login controller I have a back button to go to main page. Remember the user can access login from two different ways. by clicking on the image or clicking login in the main controller directly. So the issue is the back button does work properly. When the login page is accessed from the main controller directly, then the back button works fine it takes you to the main page. However, if you click on any of the thumbnails the second controller will try to open but since your not logged in the login page will show and when you click the back button to send you to the main controller, it won't go to main instead it will reload the same page and you kind of stock in a loop you have to login or exit the app. any ideas why?

The First ViewController Identifier is set to "mainImages".

```
- (IBAction)backToMain:(id)sender {

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

     NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
     UIViewController * MI = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainImages"];
     UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

     if (navController) {
         [navController pushViewController:MI animated:NO];
     }

}
```

I also tried this but no luck:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

UIViewController * MI = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainImages"];
[self presentViewController:MI animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you are presenting as modal:

```
- (IBAction)backToMain:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows firstObject];
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)window.rootViewController;
    [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];


 }
```

Comment: Have you connected this method.

Comment: I edited the code above. I am pretty sure is the problem. I used the break point and no matter what happens as long as the user logged out it will reload login.

Comment: I've made a change. It's important to know if you are presenting modal or in the navigation controller stack.

Comment: @Program_ming Have you try the last version, be sure You completion block is fire.

Comment: I am presenting a modal

Comment: Ok, And with the currently first option, what's happens, go back only a step ?

Comment: Using your code I get the same. It reloads the login page. Maybe the new method that I added above shouldn't be in the ViewDidAppear. btw I get this in the console. [641:117592] This is method is called

Comment: Yes, you are wright the problem is this code (in viewDidApear), move (at the moment) to the viewDidLoad in order to be fire only once.

Comment: I did, now it only firing once. So when i click back to main, it does not go back to main instead just closes the login and your viewing the second controller. using the code above, you provided

Comment: @Program_ming try this new option (It´s a bit heavy, but must work)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "go back" from the login view to any other view (in this case 2 of them), you should try using a Modal Segue, a modal segue lose the navigation controller view stack but allow you to dismiss the login view and go back to you last view.

On the first (or thumbnail images view controller) show your new modal view as this:

```
UIViewController *modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then, to dismiss (on login view controller):

```
- (IBAction)backToMain:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: The first two lines should go where in the thumbnail images view controller?

Comment: With this code I go back to second controller not main